# Invoking Runtime Delay in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel, delay

I am new to Camel and I am trying to implement a functionality of changing the default delay  of Camel by setting a new delay for the Route. I am stopping the Route and starting it but it seems to consider the default delay rather than considering the new one. My Code for SpringCamelTester.java goes as follows:

```
public class SpringCamelTester {

    private ApplicationContext context = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Context.xml");
        CamelContext cc = (CamelContext) context.getBean("testingDelay");

        RouteContext cc2 = cc.getRoute("s2d").getRouteContext();

        cc2.setDelayer((long) 5000);
        cc.stopRoute("s2d");
        cc.startRoute("s2d");

        Thread.sleep(50000);
    }
}
```

My Context.xml goes as follows:

```
<camelContext id="testingDelay" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="s2d">
        <from uri="file:D:/Workshop/Rough/CamelTest/CamelSink/Source?noop=true" />

        <!-- <log message="Output of message from Queue: ${in.body}"/> -->
        <bean ref="fileProcessor" method="propcess"/>

        <to uri="file:D:/Workshop/Rough/CamelTest/CamelSink/Destination" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Camel only support to set the delayer time when it loading the route.
You can setup the delayer value at the route just like this

```
<camelContext id="testingDelay" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="s2d" delayer="20000">
        <from uri="file:D:/Workshop/Rough/CamelTest/CamelSink/Source?noop=true" />

        <!-- <log message="Output of message from Queue: ${in.body}"/> -->
        <bean ref="fileProcessor" method="propcess"/>

        <to uri="file:D:/Workshop/Rough/CamelTest/CamelSink/Destination" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
```